# DecimalFormat with RoundingMode.HALF_UP

Tags: math, kotlin, rounding, number-formatting

Having a simple code

```
import java.math.RoundingMode
import java.text.DecimalFormat
  
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val f = DecimalFormat("#.##").apply { roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_UP }
  println(f.format(-0.025f))
  println(f.format(-0.015f))
  println(f.format(-0.005f))
  println(f.format(0.005f))
  println(f.format(0.015f))
  println(f.format(0.025f))
}
```

I got the following output:

> -0,03 <-- ok
>
> -0,01 <-- expecting -0,02
>
> -0 <-- expecting -0,01
>
> 0 <-- expecting 0,01
>
> 0,01 <--- expecting 0,02
>
> 0,03 <-- ok

Do I correctly understand `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` meaning?

**P.S.**
I had found, that using doubles instead of floats solve the problem. So `println(f.format(0.005.toDouble()))` works, giving expected `0.1`.

Comment: my suggestion: never ever use float or double if you want exact numbers to show up ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What the documentation says about `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` is:

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.

While that might look like the behavior you're looking for, these are decimal floats, and they have a hard time being represented in memory. There's a great read on it on [the Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

So, it seems that -0.005 and -0.015 both are closer (nearest neighbor) to -0.01 than anything else, so they both are formatted as -0.01. To make your code do what you want it do to, is to change your rounding mode to:

```
roundingMode = RoundingMode.UP
```

The output of running that is:

```
-0.03
-0.02
-0.01
0.01
0.02
0.03
```

Which is exactly what you expected. If you do want your code to work, you can use the following approach though:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
import java.math.RoundingMode
import java.text.DecimalFormat

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f = DecimalFormat("#.##").apply { roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_UP }
    println(f.format( BigDecimal("-1000.045")))
    println(f.format( BigDecimal("-1000.035")))
    println(f.format( BigDecimal("-1000.025")))
    println(f.format( BigDecimal("-1000.015")))
    println(f.format( BigDecimal("-1000.005")))
}
```

Comment: The documentation says: *"...in which case round up"*

Comment: Unfortunately (and obviuosly) UP gives 0,01 for 0.002, for example :( It seems (and I hope) the problem is actual for only numbers close to zero.

Comment: @forpas oops! I copied the documentation from the enum value below. Thanks for spotting!

Comment: @Alexey, did you link I provided? It doesn't happen with numbers close to zero, it happens will all floating point numbers.

Comment: @Roland depends what you want. I've updated my code with something which probably is what you wanted though

Comment: @ErikPragt Using `BigDecimal` works fine. But I not too much like conversions sequence Float->String->BigDecimal->String. Tried `BigDecimal(0.005.toDouble())` - also does not work, gives 0. So the only solution seems to be `f.format(BigDecimal(0.005.toString()))`

Comment: @Alexey if you don't want loss of precision, BigDecimal is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use `float` or `double` if you want exact numbers to show up. If you round and want the rounding to happen on a solid base, you don't want `float` or `double` neither ;-)

Your sample using `double` would also give wrong results. Your sample using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) will give the results you expect. So... stick with [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you want to be safe(r).

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val f = DecimalFormat("#.##").apply { roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_UP }
  println(f.format(BigDecimal("-0.025")))
  println(f.format(BigDecimal("-0.015")))
  println(f.format(BigDecimal("-0.005")))
  println(f.format(BigDecimal("0.005")))
  println(f.format(BigDecimal("0.015")))
  println(f.format(BigDecimal("0.025")))
}
```